# Is the DWG graphics file format a bitmap or vector?

Tags: graphics, bitmap, vector-graphics, dwg

Is the DWG graphics file format a bitmap format or a vector format?  Or can it be either?

[DWG wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwg)

Comment: Excellent answer, @Rahul_Banerjee.  If you put your comment into an answer, I will accept it over the other current answers.

Comment: Moved my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll restate what has already been written below, in layman's terms:

DWG stores 3D geometry, not images. Geometry is described in terms of points, lines, polygons, etc.

While a 2D vector image can also be described in terms of points, lines and polygons (aka "shapes"), a file format for 3D geometry is never used for storing 2D vector images.

As for bitmaps, they are a completely different kettle of fish and DWG is definitely not related to that.

Thanks for the suggestion to put this in an answer, Rob!

Answer (score 1):

DWG is a cad file extension and contains the data to mathematically describe the object(s) being modeled.
Cad programs use the data contained in the DWG file to dynamically generate different views (images) of the model.  DWG files by themselves are neither bitmap or vector images.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an image file.  It stores information about CAD models.  See this page to learn about the complicated interior:

http://libdwg.sourceforge.net/en/index.html